# Good Gridster Demos?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, gridster

Are there any good demonstrations of Gridster online on jsfiddle or jsbin, etc.??

Is there a way to control the maximum height and width of the gridster table? and make the widgets play inside this container only? does gridster use Jquery-UI by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a lot of great gridster example here: http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/#demos

Answer (score 3):

Here is a jsbin demo which you can edit to control the active height and width [here](http://jsbin.com/oziquh/7/edit).
 which I put together to answer your question. For some reason it was deleted by a zealous mod previously, but here's the link again anyway, as that's what you asked for.

Gridster does not require Jquery UI.

Comment: thanks mcintyre321, i thought jquery UI can be used for resizing, do you know of any alternatives for adding a resizing feature?

Comment: also is there a way to strict the columns added by the grid??, is it possible to strict the rows and cols of the grid??

Comment: http://gridster.net/#resize_widget_method

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oziquh/18/edit Click on the first widget and voila. You should really be trying it out yourself though mate!

Comment: Thanks @mcintyre321 i did try before but encountered endless bugs, my jquery skills is pathetic :)

hope it improved now..